# Loading constants at program launch

Tags: java, static

When I define static or constant members, for example:
`public static final Font BIG_FONT = new Font("", Font.BOLD, 18);`
I noticed that they only load when I first use them, which either results in freezes during the runtime or forces me to somehow preload them by forcefully 'using' the constant at the program launch.

**Aren't static members of such type supposed to be loaded at program launch rather than wait to be loaded on first use? How can I make sure they are preloaded?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, statics are initialized when the class is first used, not when the static member itself is first used. You can force "pre-loading" by using any other member of that class, not necessarily the static field itself.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Static initializers are executed when the class is first loaded.

The Java Runtime does not go out of its way to initialize every class as soon as you start the program; that would be a very bad idea.

Comment: You can't, AFAIK.  You need to explicitly load the class in your code.

Comment: But some of my classes that contain such static members cannot be instantiated without certain information which is only available when the program is already running.

Comment: You don't need to instantiate it; you just need to load it (eg, `Something.class.toString();`

Comment: Try accessing any static member.

Comment: Nope... I've added a `public static boolean loaded = false` member to that class and change it to true, but the `Font` member is still only loaded when it was first used. (which results, yet again, in a small freeze-up)

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is create a static loader method and include it in during your initialization method.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned statics are initialized when the class is first loaded.

One way to force this would be to either create an instance of the class in question or create (program) a distinct (new) class containing the statics and instantiate it as soon as the program starts.  However, I'm not sure I would recommend either practice as they tie up memory that might be better used elsewhere.